# Allow content of child component to remain the same when switching between active child elements in parent

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to create a set of dynamic tabs, some of which may have input fields that will need to persist (not between page refreshes, but just between switching tabs), or some will have a lot of dynamic content. The user should be able to open multiple tabs of the same component type and the content of each one should "persist" when switching back and forth. Hope that makes some sense.

**Here is my "PowerTabContainer" that manages the tabs / handles clicks / displays the tabs and content etc:**

```
<script>
    // #PowerTabContainer
    import PowerTab from "./PowerTab.svelte";

    export let initialTabItems = [];
    export let activeTabIndex = 0;

    let tabItems = initialTabItems;

    const handleClick = tabIndex => () => {
        activeTabIndex = tabIndex;
    };
</script>

<!-- Outer container -->
<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
    <!-- Tabs container -->
    <div class="flex flex-row bg-gray-950 border-b border-gray-700 pl-1">
        {#each tabItems as item, index}
            <PowerTab
                index={index}
                title={item.title}
                icon={item.icon}
                active={activeTabIndex === index}
                onClick={handleClick(index)}
            />
        {/each}
    </div>

    <!-- Tab content -->
    <div class="w-full flex-grow">
        {#if activeTabIndex === index}
            <svelte:component this={item.component} />
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the "PowerTab" component:**

```
<script>
    // #PowerTab
    export let index = -1;
    export let active = false;
    export let title = "No title";
    export let icon = "bi bi-emoji-smile";
    export let onClick = () => { /* Passed from PowerTabsContainer */ };
</script>

<button on:click="{onClick}" powertabindex="{index}" class="gap-2 px-2 py-1 rounded-t-md hover:!bg-gray-600" class:active={active}>
    <i class="{icon}"></i>
    <span class="font-light">{title} ({index + 1})</span>
</button>

<style>
    .active { @apply bg-gray-600 cursor-pointer; }
    button:not(.active) {@apply bg-gray-700 cursor-pointer; }
</style>
```

**And finally, here is the +page.svelte that contains the tabs container with the original set of tabs:**

```
<script>
    import PowerTabsContainer from "../components/PowerTabs/PowerTabsContainer.svelte";
    import Dashboard from "../components/TabItems/Dashboard.svelte";
    import Settings from "../components/TabItems/Settings.svelte";

    export let initialTabItems = [
        {
            title: "Dashboard",
            icon: "bi bi-house",
            component: Dashboard
        },
        {
            title: "Settings",
            icon: "bi bi-gear",
            component: Settings
        }
    ];
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>PowerTabs Testing</title>
</svelte:head>

<div class="flex h-full">
    <!-- Left panel -->
    <div class="z-10 w-96 bg-gray-800 border-r-2 border-gray-500 shadow-lg shadow-black">

    </div>
    <!-- Power tabs -->
    <PowerTabsContainer initialTabItems={initialTabItems} />
</div>
```

To test, in the dashboard component, I currently have it setting a random number in the JS and just displaying it, and in the settings component I currently have a couple of test input fields. But when switching between the 2 tab items it resets them completely every time a user clicks.

I think I am getting a little mixed up as I am treating the "components" like instances of "class" objects, but I am so new to svelte I thought I had better check if I am a million miles away, or if this is even possible?

---

Just to note, I have already tried a couple of different things. I found two examples online of people making a tab setup with Svelte, but both of them didn't say anything about keeping the state of the tab content. I also found that Svelte has some "Tab" related modules, but testing this also failed to keep state of the content.

And finally, I also tried using "svelte/store" with the "writable" and "set" methods, but this just simply didn't work as far as I could tell. I assume this is actually for a different case, closer to persisting data across page refreshes or something.

Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated, thanks!

### Update!

---

I've actually managed to get something working, as I realized that the issue is occurring when the "tabItems" array gets updated. So now I am displaying the contents of the tab like so:

```
<!-- Tab content -->
<div class="w-full flex-grow">
    {#each tabItems as item, index}
        <svelte:component this={item.component} active={activeTabIndex === index} />
    {/each}
</div>
```

Basically now I am rendering all of the "tabItems" at the same time, but passing whether it is active or not into the component itself, and then in the component the "active" switch just hides it if it isn't active.

This actually does work but as you can probably tell this is far from ideal as this means every tab component now has to handle the hiding / showing of itself from within, which shouldn't be it's responsibility, it should be the tab container that handles that. Also this would break as soon as the user adds or removes another tab anyway as the array would be updating.

Just thought it was worth sharing this update!

Comment: I am also building an app with tabs that preserve user choices between tab flips. I settled for a persistent object at the top level (App.svelte) with accessor functions for getting and setting its properties, and pass those accessor functions down via props to child components. The child components on load see that a local variable is uninitialized and call the "get last choice" accessor function. When the user makes a choice, they call the "set last choice" function. A single object at the top level can carry the remembered choices of all children components, with nesting and prop:value refs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comparison of `components` being `classes` is quite accurate. If you think of it in terms of classes, the thing you import and save in the variable "component" is the "class". When you reference it as an element e.g. (<PowerTab .../>) a "object" of the "class is created. This also happens when you call `<svelte:component this={displayComponent} />`. A "object" is created with its own state, which is recreated/rebuild, whenever the `displayComponent` changes.

There are a few possibilities to save the data to saving state of the data on component switch.

### 1. stores

I am not sure how you have tried using stores, but stores are made for the purpose of saving data outside of components and sharing data between them. I tried your setup using stores and it worked for me.

To use stores successfully you have to have a separate js file containing the stores.

You can implement the stores in a few different ways for your use case.

You can make a writeable for every text input and bind the value to it.

```js
// store.js 
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

export const dashboardTextBox = writable("");
```

```html
<script>
// Dashboard.svelte
    import {dashboardTextBox} from "./store.js";
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={$dashboardTextBox}>
```

another way would be to create a writeable object and bind to that object

```js
// store.js 
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

export const dashboard = writable({text: "name"});
```

```html
<script>
// Dashboard.svelte
    import {dashboard} from "./store.js";
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={$dashboard.text}>
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={$dashboard.checked}>
<!-- the attributes don't have to exist on the object before hand btw -->
```

There are pros and cons to both ways. When you make `writeable`'s for every value, you only that component gets updated when it something changes. The **$** shorthand can be thought of as `dashboardTextBox.subscribe()` where the value is automatically listened to for change. If you listen to an object, every change to every attribute will be listened to and that could potentially lead to performance issue if you have many elements referencing to one `writeable`. But the upside is that you don't have to create a writeable for every value you want to set.

The upside of stores in general is that you can listen to them from any svelte component, by just importing them and changes to the writeables are automatically detected if you put the **$** in front of the writeable. But if you have dynamically generating tabs you would need to create a writeable for everyone of the elements, which could be annoying

### 2. Passing data as props

My preferred way, if you only want to save the state and don't have the need to share state between variables, I would pass the state as props. I would have a parent element keep the state saved somehow and bind it to the child.

In your example it could look something like this

```html
<script>
    import PowerTabsContainer from "../components/PowerTabs/PowerTabsContainer.svelte";
    import Dashboard from "../components/TabItems/Dashboard.svelte";
    import Settings from "../components/TabItems/Settings.svelte";

    export let initialTabItems = [
        {
            title: "Dashboard",
            icon: "bi bi-house",
            state: {}, // have a object tied to each tab, where the state is saved
            component: Dashboard
        },
        {
            title: "Settings",
            icon: "bi bi-gear",
            state: {},
            component: Settings
        }
    ];
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>PowerTabs Testing</title>
</svelte:head>

<div class="flex h-full">
    <!-- Left panel -->
    <div class="z-10 w-96 bg-gray-800 border-r-2 border-gray-500 shadow-lg shadow-black">

    </div>
    <!-- Power tabs -->
    <PowerTabsContainer initialTabItems={initialTabItems} />
</div>
```

```html
<script>
    // #PowerTabContainer
    import PowerTab from "./PowerTab.svelte";

  export let initialTabItems = [];
    export let activeTabIndex = 0;

    let tabItems = initialTabItems;

    $: displayTabItem = tabItems[activeTabIndex]; // refactored this a bit to make it easier to access and more svelte-like
    $: displayComponent = displayTabItem?.component; // works similarly to computed in other frameworks if you are familiar to thoose

    const handleClick = tabIndex => () => {
        activeTabIndex = tabIndex;
    };
</script>

<!-- Outer container -->
<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
    <!-- Tabs container -->
    <div class="flex flex-row bg-gray-950 border-b border-gray-700 pl-1">
        {#each tabItems as item, index}
            <PowerTab
                index={index}
                title={item.title}
                icon={item.icon}
                active={activeTabIndex === index}
                onClick={handleClick(index)}
            />
        {/each}
    </div>

    <!-- Tab content -->
    <div class="w-full flex-grow">
        {#if displayComponent !== null}
            <svelte:component this={displayComponent} bind:state={displayTabItem.state}/>
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you pass the state from the main `App` to the `PowerTabsContainer` and through `<svelte:component this={displayComponent} bind:state={displayTabItem.state} />` you bind it to the component. In the component you can further use the state and bind it to variables.

```html
<script>
// component
    export let state;
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={state.text}>
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={state.checked}>
```

If you bind the values, changes will be written to `state:{}` and because the parent components above aren't rebuild the state won't be lost. The components get the previous state when they are build again through props and nothing is lost.

I like this approach more, because stores are a pain to write and this way, you can potentially have multiple Tabs of the same component and their states won't interfere.

---

There are other ways you could deal with this, but these are, in my opinion the "best" solutions. You could just not rebuild any components and just hide every inactive tab with css, you could also use localStorage or sessionStorage to save the values and get them when you mount or have custom events in the components that send data upwards, but those solutions are all quite hack-y.

Hope this helps you on your svelte journey ;).

Comment: This is an absolutey excellent answer, not only did it solve the initial issue but also taught me so very helpful things about Svelte that I didn't know. Thanks so much for going above and beyond :)

I have gone with the second suggestion you made, as you say this would be a much more streamlined way of managing the state of each component 

Comment: While this is not exactly what my problem is, close enough!  I haven't used svelte stores in a long time, didn't see the concept as relevant all day today, but now I am wiser. Excellent explanation!